# SQL Server: Invalid column name 'avgDaysToTxn' error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
SELECT ( CASE
         WHEN SUM(numVisits) = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE                         SUM(totalSpend)/SUM(numVisits)
         END
       ) AS totalSpend ,
       ( ( SUM(daysToTxn2
             + daysToTxn3
             + daysToTxn4
             + daysToTxn5
             + daysToTxn6
             + daysToTxn7
             + daysToTxn8
             + daysToTxn9
             + daysToTxn10
             )
         ) / 9
       ) as avgDaysToTxn
FROM dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
GROUP BY avgDaysToTxn -- error here: "Invalid column name 'avgDaysToTxn'."
ORDER BY totalSpend
;
```

but I get an error, "Invalid column name 'avgDaysToTxn'." on the GROUP BY line.

Here's my incoming data:

```
daysToTxn2  daysToTxn3  daysToTxn4  daysToTxn5  daysToTxn6  daysToTxn7  daysToTxn8  daysToTxn9  daysToTxn10     numVisits       totalSpend
130 142 218 309 427 495 598 694 827 104    363.23
716 779 0   0   0   12      23      0   0    11    256.45
13  63  191 201 289 292 310 476 492   25   456.34
7   15  27  63  109 203 245 256 274    43  789.03
```

And I'd like my outgoing data to be just 2 columns. One headed with totalSpend. The other headed with avgDaysToTxn.

Could anybody help me get rid of this error while executing the code?

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  You cannot put an aggregation function in the `group by`.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I didn't know you couldn't `group by` an aggregate function. I'm trying to average the `daysToTxn` and then compare each `avgDaysToTxn` to the average `totalSpend`, so that I can determine what is the average amount spend by a person based on their average days in between transactions.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support using aliases from the currently scope query in GROUP BY or ORDER BY. You would have to duplicate your CASE statements in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

Comment: You should delete this question.  Then ask another question that provides sample data and desired results.  Non-working queries often do a surprisingly poor job of communicating what one wants to do.

Comment: @MichaelRice so I would have to use a `CASE WHEN` in my `SUM(daysToTxn...)` line?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but see if that does what you want it to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made edits to include data. Please let me know if more should be included.

Answer (score 2):

This is the order of execution in SQL

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

This means that the alias you have in the SELECT clause is not visible in the GROUP BY clause.
The only place you can use the alias created in the SELECT clause is in the ORDER BY clause since it is executed after the select. Anywhere else you would have to duplicate your statement for computed values or use the original column name (not the alias) for column names.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for explaining it so clearly, so does this mean I can't use the `clause` from the same `select` statement in the `group by` area because the grouping in the `group by` occurs before the `select` in that statement? Sorry if I worded that poorly.

Comment: If by "clause from the same select statement" you mean the column names then yes you can use them in the group by clause because they exist since the table creation. But you can't use the alias because they must have been introduced in a previous step following the logical query processing order. Since SQL Server is designed to follow this processing order there is no way for it to know values defined or evaluated in the select clause without re-evaluating it. Do a search on 'SQL Server logical processing phases', that might clear things out for you.

Comment: Or a simpler way of looking at this is that when query execution starts SQL Server says what table(s) am I working on and marks the tables to be worked on [FROM clause] , Then says any conditions for query [WHERE clause], then looks at the grouping criteria [GROUPE BY clause] ... at this stage it looks at the column names for grouping and finds the column name 'avgDaysToTxn', this column name is not a member of the column names in the table(s) marked in the FROM statement and it doesn't exist since it is not defined until we get to the SELECT clause, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        (SUM(totalSpend) / SUM(numVisits)) AS totalSpend
        , (SUM(daysToTxn2 + daysToTxn3 + daysToTxn4 + daysToTxn5 + daysToTxn6 + daysToTxn7 + daysToTxn8 + daysToTxn9 + daysToTxn10) / 9) as avgDaysToTxn
    FROM
         dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
    GROUP BY
         (SUM(daysToTxn2 + daysToTxn3 + daysToTxn4 + daysToTxn5 + daysToTxn6 + daysToTxn7 + daysToTxn8 + daysToTxn9 + daysToTxn10) / 9)
    HAVING SUM(numVisits) > 0
)
ORDER BY totalSpend;
```

Comment: Sorry for getting to this so late, and thanks for your efforts, but when I run this script, I get an, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. Expecting AS, ID, or QUOTED_ID".  Also, I get an error, "Invalid column name 'totalSpend'".

Answer (score 0):

In most SQL, `GROUP BY` does not recognize aliased columns.  Therefore you need to duplicate the formula as-is in the `SELECT` into the `GROUP BY`.  e.g.

```
SELECT ( CASE
         WHEN SUM(numVisits) = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE                         SUM(totalSpend)/SUM(numVisits)
         END
       ) AS totalSpend ,
       ( ( SUM(daysToTxn2
             + daysToTxn3
             + daysToTxn4
             + daysToTxn5
             + daysToTxn6
             + daysToTxn7
             + daysToTxn8
             + daysToTxn9
             + daysToTxn10
             )
         ) / 9
       ) as avgDaysToTxn
FROM dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
GROUP BY ( ( SUM(daysToTxn2
             + daysToTxn3
             + daysToTxn4
             + daysToTxn5
             + daysToTxn6
             + daysToTxn7
             + daysToTxn8
             + daysToTxn9
             + daysToTxn10
             )
         ) / 9
       )
ORDER BY totalSpend
```

Comment: you can't group by an aggregate function. The value of the aggregate function is derived from the grouping itself. You can't compute the value of the aggregate until you already have a group.

Comment: You can't `WHERE` an aggregate, but I've never had a problem with `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sorry for getting to this so late, but when I run this script, I got an, "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause." error. Thanks for your efforts though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error in your `group by` clause is two-fold:

**Problem #1.** The proximate cause of the error is that newly-created columns in the result set can't be referenced by name — or ordinal position, for that matter, as allowed by  `order by` — in the `group by` clause: you have to replicate the expression **exactly**. SQL is not known for being a terse language. Learn to love repetitive typing.

**Problem #2.** You have a bigger though. You're trying to partition things into groups for summarization based on their **already summarized** values. What does something like the following (essentially what you're trying to do) mean?

```
select sum(x) , sum(y)
from foo
group by sum(y)
```

How are your groups defined? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Will do on the repetitive typing :) To answer your questions, I believe the select statement you wrote is grouping by an aggregate function, so it won't work. Am I correct or wrong? My `daysToTxn` columns are all `int` and accept `null`. My incoming `numVisits` data is `int` and accepts `null`. The `totalSpend` incoming data is `float` data type and accepts `null`. I'm trying to average the `daysToTxn` and then compare each `avgDaysToTxn` to the average `totalSpend`, so that I can determine what is the average amount spend by a person based on their average days in between transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just dispense with the `group by`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN numVisits> THEN totalSpend / numVisits
        END) AS totalSpend ,
       ((daysToTxn2 + daysToTxn3 + daysToTxn4 + daysToTxn5 + daysToTxn6 + daysToTxn7 + daysToTxn8 + daysToTxn9 + daysToTxn10) /
        ((case when daysToTxn2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn5 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn6 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn7 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn8 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn9 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when daysToTxn10 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
        ) as avgDaysToTxn
FROM dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
ORDER BY totalSpend
```

Comment: Sorry for getting to this so late and thanks for your efforts. This script compiles, but I need it to organize the query based on `avgDaysToTxn`.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you don't need to do grouping in the first hand. Instead, just do the calculation of columns and then in outer query, do the aggregation and grouping.

```
SELECT SUM(totalSpend) totalSpend, avgDaysToTxn FROM
(
SELECT ( CASE
         WHEN isnull(numVisits,0) = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE                         totalSpend/numVisits
         END
       ) AS totalSpend ,
       ( ( daysToTxn2
             + daysToTxn3
             + daysToTxn4
             + daysToTxn5
             + daysToTxn6
             + daysToTxn7
             + daysToTxn8
             + daysToTxn9
             + daysToTxn10
             )
          / 9
       ) as avgDaysToTxn
FROM dbo.ANTHEM_IDS_JR 
) A
GROUP BY avgDaysToTxn -- error here: "Invalid column name 'avgDaysToTxn'."
ORDER BY totalSpend
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for getting to this so late, and thanks for your efforts, but the calculation of the `totalSpend` and `avgDaysToTxn` seem to be a bit high, but the `group by` statement worked.

Comment: May I ask what significance the `A` has after the `select` statement?

Comment: You have to alias the query or it will result in an error. So the "A" serves as an alias to the results of that query.